# how get the Geographic location values of Preference panel of Lotus Sametime

Tags: lotus, sametime

i am using IBM Lotus Sametime 8.0.2. in Geographic location link of Preference panel of File menu have some fields like Personal address, City, Postal code etc. Can i get the values of these fields in a Java program or using Sametime SDK (without using any plug-ins).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get them from the Sametime Java SDk, by first adding the user to a watchlist, and then querying their user attributes.